# Participio Activo y Participio Pasivo de Sustantivos

Tags: gramática, participio

¿Existen reglas para la formación de los participios activo y pasivo en relación a sustantivos?

> Ejemplo 1: El participio activo de *Referir* es *Referente*. Pero cual es el participio pasivo de Referir?
>
> Ejemplo 2: En la frase: "El primer sumando en la ecuación..", es *Sumando* el participio pasivo de *Sumar*?  Cual sería el participio activo de Sumar?

Comment: Estas preguntas parecen las de deberes escolares. ¿Qué piensas que son? o ¿cuál es la duda que tienes?

Comment: Referido? referente ? sumante? sumado? divisor? dividio?

Comment: @guifa - No estoy de acuerdo en que parezca tarea (deberes), pero aunque lo fuera, creo yo que lo más importante es que OP muestre que haya hecho un esfuerzo por entender or encontrar la respuesta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El **participio pasivo** es una forma verbal que se usa en dos tipos de construcciones gramaticales: la voz pasiva perifrástica (por ejemplo: *«Los pacientes fueron referidos a otro hospital»*) y los tiempos verbales compuestos (por ejemplo: *«Nos hemos referido muchas veces a este asunto»*). El participio pasivo como se usa en la voz pasiva es variable (tiene género y número) y puede funcionar como adjetivo (*los pacientes referidos al hospital*). Muchos participios pasivos de esta clase se han transformado en sustantivos, como por ejemplo *amado*, *tirada*, *supuesto*, etc., pero esto es un proceso léxico, no gramatical, es decir: no hay una regla que permita usar o transformar cualquier participio pasivo en un sustantivo.

El **participio activo** es una forma verbal que hoy en día se usa muy poco regularmente. Tiene número gramatical pero es invariable en género, y puede funcionar como adjetivo o como sustantivo. Los participios activos terminan en *-nte* (*-ante, -ente, -iente* según la terminación del verbo).

El participio activo de *sumar* sería regularmente *sumante*, pero si bien la palabra es entendible por cualquier hablante de español, no es una palabra que realmente se use. Su significado vendría a ser "la persona que suma". Otros ejemplos de este tipo serían *sumariante* ("persona que toma nota de una denuncia policial", *demandante* "persona que demanda legalmente algo", *dependiente* "persona que trabaja bajo las órdenes de otra"), etc.

*Sumando* es el gerundio del verbo. Los gerundios se pueden usar a veces como sustantivos, como en *sumando*, que significa "cualquiera de los números que son sumados en una operación de adición". De nuevo, esto es léxico. La mayoría de los gerundios no se usan así, y hacerlo suena técnico o formal. Otros ejemplos de gerundios como sustantivos son: *educando* ("persona que está siendo educada, alumno"), *graduando* ("persona que se está graduando en una carrera").

Comment: Que sepa yo, cuando es participio participio, el activo no varía (o quizás hoy día mejor dicho variaba) en número, eso solo es cuando se ha adjetivizado que adquiere la variación en número; además podía tomar pronombres que hoy día no puede.

Comment: @guifa cuando es utilizado como verbo el participio es conjugado de  tanto en plural como singular de la misma forma, pero cuando es utilizado como adjetivo/sustantivo/advervios, este se pluraliza

Comment: Esta es una excelente explicación; toca precisamente en el uso que estoy buscando, que es técnico en su caracter. Mi intención es usar los dos participios como sustantivos para referirme al Agente, y a Lo Producido por el Agente a través de la acción. Muchas gracias @pablodf76.

Comment: @jorgeO-L ten cuidado que hoy en día para referir al que hace algo, lo normal es usar la terminación *-dor* (la diferencia es mínima si de verdad existe entre las dos en la forma sustantival)

Answer (score 1):

Si digo "el examinando se presentará mañana a las 10'00", la palabra "examinando" no es un gerundio, sino que se ha convertido en un sustantivo que procede del participio de futuro pasivo latino, que termina en "andus" o en "endus". Por tanto, la palabra "examinando" significa "el que ha de ser examinado" y no tiene ninguna relación con el gerundio, aunque coincida con él en la desinencia.

Answer (score 1):

1. El participio activo del verbo ser es ente,
2. La terminación -nte que añadimos a los participios activos de los verbos procede de ente
3. Dicha terminación se toma de ente porque este denota entidad o significa 'el que es'.

Sin embargo:

1. El participio activo del verbo ser no es ente. El único participio que actualmente tienen, de forma general, los verbos españoles, es el de perfecto (por ejemplo sido, para el verbo ser, o comido para comer). Solo algunos verbos tienen entre sus derivados los llamados participios activos, que hoy se consideran sustantivos (como presidente) o adjetivos (como atacante o cantante). El verbo ser tuvo en el pasado una forma de participio activo hoy perdida, pero no era ente sino eseyente.
2. La terminación -nte no procede de ente. Nuestro sustantivo ente (que, como se ha dicho, no es el participio del verbo ser) sí que deriva, sin embargo, de ens, entis, participio de presente del verbo latino esse ('ser, estar'). Pero el hecho crucial no es que el participio del verbo ser en latín tuviera esta forma entis, sino que todos los participios de presente del latín tenían esta misma forma: e-ntis, ama-ntis, lege-ntis, capie-ntis, etc. Obviando la raíz verbal y la vocal temática que quedan a la izquierda del guion, en todas estas formas lo que encontramos es la secuencia -nt- y la terminación -is, desinencia de caso genitivo.

Esta secuencia -nt- es un infijo, un elemento que se inserta en el interior de una palabra, y es una marca morfológica que indica un subtipo concreto de declinación por el que se guían algunas de las palabras que forman parte de la tercera declinación latina. Este mismo infijo, y este mismo submodelo de declinación (llamado precisamente temas en -nt-), está presente también en otras lenguas, como el griego clásico. Aunque por este modelo de temas en -nt- se declinan solo unos pocos sustantivos y adjetivos, en la práctica es muy productivo, porque es el modelo por el que se declinan todos los participios de presente activos de todos los verbos latinos y varios de los participios del griego clásico.

3. La terminación -nte no se toma de ente porque este denote al ser. El hecho de que esta secuencia -nt- aparezca no solo en ente, sino en todos los participios de los verbos latinos e incluso en otros adjetivos (como prudentis, 'prudente'), sustantivos (como /leontos/, 'león' en griego) y determinantes (como /panta/, 'todo' en griego) prueba que esa -nt- no ha sido nunca, a lo largo de su historia, marca de entidad o de existencia. Nunca, por sí sola, ha denotado al ser, al ente. Llegó a denotar, en latín, al ente al entrar en interacción con el verbo ser, pero entró en contacto con este verbo, como con todos los demás verbos latinos, pues no es más que una marca morfológica de la que los verbos se sirven para declinar una de sus formas no personales, el participio.

Lo que históricamente existe es este infijo -nt- y no la terminación -nte. Recordemos que en las formas amantis o legentis la terminación –is es marca de genitivo, pero este es solo uno de los seis casos que tienen las declinaciones latinas. Estas declinaciones establecen distintas terminaciones en función del caso, del género y del número: un participio como entis puede tener potencialmente hasta 24 desinencias, es decir, 24 terminaciones después del infijo -nt-entem, entis, enti, entium, entia, etc.) que se encargan precisamente de marcar el caso, el número y el género. Nada, por tanto, en la morfología histórica de este elemento -nt- impide que las palabras que se forman con él tengan una forma distinta para el género femenino; es más, históricamente este infijo ha formado parte de palabras que explícitamente diferenciaban el género.

Por último. Es cierto que el español conserva este infijo fundamentalmente en la terminación -nte, y es fácil caer en el error de creer que la emplea solo para referirse a la persona que realiza la acción del verbo (presidente el que preside, cantante el que canta, atacante el que ataca). Sin embargo esto no es una verdad absoluta: ni todos los verbos se refieren al agente con esta terminación, ni siempre que esta terminación aparece se asocia a la persona que lleva a cabo la acción del verbo.

Los que luchan, los que inventan, los que trabajan, los que corren, etc. no son los luchantes, los inventantes, los trabajantes, etc. sino el luchador y la luchadora, el inventor y la inventora, el trabajador y la trabajadora. El español actual conserva, además, casos en los que este infijo es más una mera marca gramatical (heredera de un antiguo participio que hoy ya no se siente como tal): mediante, de mediar; durante, de durar; o bastante, de bastar. Y de hecho, en el español de otras épocas estas palabras tenían forma en plural (era, por ejemplo, posible decir ellas durantes).

Nada en la morfología histórica de nuestra lengua, ni en la de las lenguas de las que la nuestra procede, impide que las palabras que se forman con este componente tengan una forma para el género femenino. Las lenguas evolucionan y en esa evolución se transforman. Estos cambios se deben a muchas causas, algunas son causas internas (evoluciones fonéticas, por ejemplo); otras son externas, el contacto con otras lenguas o el cambio en las sociedades que las hablan. Para que una lengua tenga voces como presidenta, solo hacen falta dos cosas: que haya mujeres que presidan y que haya hablantes que quieran explícitamente expresar que las mujeres presiden. Si esas dos circunstancias se dan, ninguna supuesta terminación, por muy histórica que sea su huella, frenará el uso de la forma femenina (pregúntese el lector por qué no se han levantado voces contra el uso del femenino sirvienta). Pero es que, además, en el caso de este infijo concreto, la historia de nuestra lengua y la de las lenguas que la precedieron pueden llegar a avalar el uso de voces como presidenta, pues al hilo de esta explicación parecen ser menos conservadoras que la variedad actual.

Comment: Muy útil esta contestación; muchísimas gracias Berta por el esfuerzo que invirtió usted en ella. Bastante material por degerir. 

Answer (score 0):

No nos confundamos,

El participio pasivo es la conjugación del la acción en pasado en voz pasiva

Mientras que el participio activo puede ser un se refiere a la parte activa de la acción y actúa en el tiempo presente (por eso su terminación en "nte".

Ejemplos :

> el referente ha referido una forma :
>
> > el referente(Activo) es el que refiere

> > el referido(pasivo) es sobre el que se actúa

En tu ejemplo "***Sumando***" **NO** es el participio pasivo, ese es un **Gerundio**.

Para identificar la diferencia: el Gerundio es el presente constante,
mientras que el Participio Pasivo es algo que ya sucedió en voz pasiva.

la diferencia entre el participio pasivo y gerundio esta en la terminacion -ndo- y "do"

> Gerundio : "Yendo","comiendo","viviendo"

> Participio pasivo : "ido" , "comido", vivido"

Así que el participio pasivo de sumar es "***sumado***",
y el participio activo sería "Sumante"

En inglés el participio pasivo es llamado "presente perfecto"

*--edit*

*al parecer el Gerundio también es conocido como presente participio pasivo, así que ahora tenemos dos definiciones.*

el presente participio pasivo de referir (gerundio) seria :**refiriendo**

Comment: Esta es una aclaración importante. Gracias @Erin. Modifiqué la pregunta para indicar que me refiero específicamente a Sustantivos.

Comment: con algo mas de investigacion anadi, el gerundi es el presente participio pasivo

Answer (score -1):

Aquí puedes encontrar una explicación a los participios:

https://www.delcastellano.com/participio-presente-activo-espanol/

https://www.delcastellano.com/participio-futuro-espanol/

Interesante ver que aunque "sumando" es el gerundio del verbo sumar, sin embargo en este ejemplo, como elemento en una ecuación matemática, "sumando" expresa "*el que va a ser sumado*" que se corresponde la forma participio de futuro pasivo.